# Внедрения зависимостей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне организовать внедрения зависимостей в 3-ох уровневой приложения с DAL, BLL i WEB в ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Интерфейсы + Конструкторы с параметрами + Контейнер (можно и без него, но тогда руками создавать экземпляры рабочих классов). Кстати ASP.Net Core уже есть встроенная реализация контейнера DI,очень удобно, рекомендую.

Comment: да, но у меня есть 3 проекта в 1 решение , и что мне делать в BLL и в WEB создавать 2 контейнера?

Comment: Контейнер нужен один, его "эксплуатирует" тот слой, который использует BLL и DAL, т.е. в вашем случае WEB.

Comment: у меня в проекте WEB  - ето проект MVC. Он включает в себя проект BLL (Library) . BLL включает в себя DAL(Library). Где мне создавать етот контейнер. Если би у меня бил би 1 проект в MVC я би его там и создал а так я не знаю

Comment: Тема объемная, почитайте доки для [ASP.Net Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще внедрение зависимостей производится одним из следующих способов:

- Через конструктор;
- Через метод класса (Setter или свойство (для C#));
- Через интерфейс;

Чтобы не заниматься реализацией внедрения и созданием объектов вручную, лучше использовать какой-нибудь контейнер. Например, [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: Почему не родной мелкософтовский Unity?